# How to limit an account to only have one weeks access

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a subscription web simulation for my school task. But I don't know to limit my user account for only 1 week or maybe 1 month.

I tried to search the problem in the internet but I didn't find it

What I'm expected is to make my users have limited time account for just 1 week, so after 1 week my users would like to pay again for another week.

Comment: This question is far too broad for this platform. Take a step back and think logically about it: What information do you need stored here? You need a date that the user starts his subscription, and a date when the subscription ends. Then check if the current date is between those dates - done!

Comment: provide your database table and login code. So that we can provide you a clear code

Comment: Set registered date column in database users table (maybe), every time user tries to view some page check current date with the registered date

Comment: i would advice you to handle it in MySQL only, see mine mine suggestion and example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would advice to handle it totally in MySQL.

MySQL 5.7+ table example

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    name VARCHAR(255)
  , account_start_datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  , account_expire_datetime DATETIME AS (account_start_datetime + INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
); 

INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES('Ghifari');
```

Keep in mind because `account_expire_datetime DATETIME AS (account_start_datetime + INTERVAL 1 WEEK)` is a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) you would have alteast have to MySQL 5.7+

Then you can use `account_expire_datetime >= NOW()` to check is the account is still valid.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 user
WHERE
   user.name = 'Ghifari'
 AND
   account_expire_datetime >= NOW()
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QXDaMSKu7M9urkzqJDXh7/1)

**Note:** the demo also has a expire test case which is the second query.

The solution is a bit harder under MySQL 5.7 .

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    name VARCHAR(255)
  , account_start_datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  , account_expire_datetime DATETIME
); 

INSERT INTO user(name, account_start_datetime, account_expire_datetime) VALUES('Ghifari', DEFAULT, account_start_datetime + INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QXDaMSKu7M9urkzqJDXh7/4)

**Note**: the demo also has a expire test case which is the second query.

> What I'm expected is to make my users have limited time account for
>   just 1 week, so after 1 week my users would like to pay again for
>   another week.

Then use the `UPDATE`

**Update for the generated column approach MySQL 5.7+**

```
UPDATE
 user 
SET 
 account_start_datetime = NOW()
WHERE
 name = 'username'
```

**Update for versions under MySQL 5.7**

```
UPDATE
 user 
SET 
   account_start_datetime = NOW()
 , account_expire_datetime = account_start_datetime + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
WHERE
 name = 'username'
```

> But I dont know to limit my user account for only 1 week or maybe 1
>   month.

Use `INTERVAL 1 WEEK` for one week and `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` when you need one  month in the above examples.

Comment: Thanks sir it really helped me 

Answer (score -1):

When user logged into system for the 1st time you can save the current date and time via timestamp. Then write a php code where when someone try to login to system it will check last date and inside a condition count number of days .